# Android WebView with Jetpack Compose not rendering Mantine UI (React) components properly

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-webview, gradle-kotlin-dsl, mantine, geckoview

**Description**

I've developed a React website using the Mantine UI framework, and it works seamlessly across various browsers and devices. Now, I'm trying to create an Android app using Jetpack Compose that displays a WebView of the website. However, I've encountered an issue where some Mantine UI components, such as modals and the sidebar, fail to render correctly in the Android Webview, but does work in a regular android browser like Chrome.

**Problem Description:**

The modal background blurs as expected, but the modal itself and all it's contents does not appear.
This issue is specific to Android; the website functions properly in a regular browser and on iOS.
Webview permissions have been granted, including allowing JavaScript, but the problem persists.

Here's the code I'm using to display the WebView:

```
AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    factory = { context ->
        WebView(context).apply {
             setupWebView(this)
             loadUrl("https://v6.mantine.dev/core/modal/")
        }
    }
)
```

**Attempts and Observations:**

I tried various different ways of implementing the built in Webview into my app to see if I could resolve the issue, but none worked. I've also ensured the Webview isn't missing any permissions that's preventing it from working.

I've explored alternative WebView options and tested Mozilla's Geckoview, which renders the Mantine UI components correctly. However, I'm struggling to integrate Geckoview into my project due to Gradle build configuration differences.

I used this guide to try implement it, but failed:

https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/consumer/geckoview-quick-start.html

**My Gradle Build Configuration:**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.myapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.myapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")

    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0")

    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.5.4")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

**Question:**

1. Has anyone faced challenges with Mantine UI components failing to render correctly within an Android WebView using Jetpack Compose?
2. Could someone offer guidance on seamlessly integrating Mozilla's Geckoview or other WebView libraries into a Jetpack Compose project? Alternatively, suggestions on resolving issues with the default WebView to ensure proper functionality would be greatly appreciated. Please take my current Kotlin Gradle build configuration into account.

**I appreciate any insights, workarounds, or examples that could help resolve this problem. Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

As I checked your problem. You are missing the one line `settings.javaScriptEnabled = true` which causes the error. Because default it is **false** so `JavaScript` will not work and React is also a part of `JavaScript`.

I have checked below example in my emulator and it works and open the model dialog with content.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.activity.compose.BackHandler
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView

@Composable
fun WebViewDemoScree() {
    var backEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var webView: WebView? = null
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                    override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                        backEnabled = view.canGoBack()
                    }
                }
                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

                loadUrl("https://v6.mantine.dev/core/modal/")
                webView = this
            }
        }, update = {
            webView = it
        })

    BackHandler(enabled = backEnabled) {
        webView?.goBack()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for your reply.


I tried out your code both on a real Samsung device and a Pixel 3a emulator, but with no success as the modal still doesn't show up.


Does the app need any other permissions than this in the AndroidManifest.xml file?


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


If that's not the case, could the minimum android version for the project have something to do with it? My project is currently set to have a minimum SDK version of "API 24 (Nouget; Android 7.0)".

Comment: Yes you need permission for Internet. I have already added in my project

Comment: I know that the project needs permission for internet. I already have that too, as otherwise, the rest of the webpage wouldn't be able to render. I am asking if the app needs any other permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file. I'd also like to hear if the minimum SDK version for the project could have something to do with it. Where as I currently have it set to API 24 (Nouget; Android 7.0). If none of this is the case, would it be possible to share your full project with me that you had working through Google Drive or something so I can have a look?